# My textbox class doesn't seem to be responding to my CSS

Tags: html, css

[I am using Codepen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyhY2.png) and the textbox should be in the center with a smaller width, but no matter what I add to the .box area of the CSS, it doesn't respond. I can confirm that this isn't a web browser issue as I've tried both Google and Brave

Comment: Remove the `<style></style>` tags from the CSS field (in codepen) and it should work for you. https://codepen.io/hammuretto/pen/JjNBRdG

Comment: @HanletEscaño I removed both tags and the width works. I even tested and changed the colors, but the textbox remains in the same spot. On the left and not centered whatsoever

Comment: If you are trying to center the textbox itself, then the center style should be applied to its parent, and not to the textbox itself :) https://codepen.io/hammuretto/pen/JjNBRdG

Answer (score 2):

You are using html tag in css. It won't work anymore. Style tag is used when you want to write css in your html file internally. Like this -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .box {
      width: 10%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

But if you write css in a separate file, you needn't use the `<style></style>` tag. Just write the css like this -

```css
.box {
  width      : 10%;
  text-align : center;
  }
```

**And codepen gives you the ability to write HTML, CSS, and javascript separately. So, don't use  tag.**